# PopUp Blocker code detection not working

Tags: javascript, popup

I have turned on PopUp blocker in FF and Chrome. 
I have a piece of code to check PopUp is working as:

```
function checkPopUp()
{
  var myTest = window.open("about:blank","","directories=no,height=1,width=1,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,location=no");
  var popUpsBlocked = '';
  if (!myTest) {
    popUpsBlocked = true;    
  } else {
    popUpsBlocked = false; 
  }
  return popUpsBlocked;   
}
```

its working fine "onload" of the page.
But when i am using it with hyper link onclick, its not working a popup is getting opened.

```
 <a onclick="checkPopUp()" href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: Off topic comment: You can format your code as code by selecting it and using 'code' button on the panel (with zeroes and ones on it).

Comment: Thx i will make use of it in future

Answer (score 0):

Browsers allow popups during "click" event loops.  Different browsers have different configuration options under user control, but generally the default behavior is that a "click" is treated as a user willingly requesting functionality from a page.

Comment: Thx for ur comment.
But when i click Button, PopUp window function works, but in the same function there is an ajax request and in the reseponse i am calling the same Pop up function, its not opening up........
Why so ?

Answer (score 0):

The below code has been tested in FF29.0, IE9, Chrome35.0, Safari and the best part is it is working!!!

```
 var popupBlocker = {

  isPopupBlocked: function (width, height) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var popup = window.open("");
                    if (!popup) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        popup.document.open();
                        popup.document.write("<html><body onload='window.close();'></body></html>")
                        popup.document.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                }, 100);
            }

        };

  popupBlocker.isPopupBlocked();
```